# Adding image to MVC 3 Web grid column header

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, webgrid

recently i am using Web grid of MVC 3 . In one of the columns i need to display a image next to header text . Eg:  +  is this possible with MVC  Web grid.

thx

Answer (score 3):

Currently this is not possible unless you use CSS (provide the column header a style and set a background image in your CSS) or javascript.

Example with CSS3:

```
@grid.GetHtml(headerStyle: "header", columns: grid.Columns(
    grid.Column("Id"),
    grid.Column("Title")
))
```

and then in order to set some background image in the second column header using CSS3:

```
<style type="text/css">
.header th:nth-child(2) {
    background-image: url(foo.png);
}
</style>
```